# lineBreakMode of UILabel doesn't work when linked in the storyboard

Tags: ios, uilabel, autolayout, line-breaks, ibaction

I try to do my first application for ipad/iphone with Xcode. I have created an UILabel and an IBAction in ViewController.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UILabel *display;
}

- (IBAction)ChangeText;
```

I linked the variable "display" with a label I created in the Main.storyboard and the method "ChangeText" to a button.

The label and the button are placed using auto layout.

The label initially contains the text "-" and when I click on the button, the method "ChangeText" change the text of the label to a longer one:

```
- (IBAction)ChangeText{

    [display setText:@"A long text which exceeds the size of the screen I am using. A long text which exceeds the size of the screen I am using.A long text which exceeds the size of the screen I am using."];
}
```

Since the text is to long for the screen I would like to display it on several lines. So I changed the lineBreakMode and the numberOfLines of "display":

```
- (IBAction)ChangeText{

    display.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    display.numberOfLines = 0;

    [display setText:@"A long text which exceeds the size of the screen I am using. A long text which exceeds the size of the screen I am using.A long text which exceeds the size of the screen I am using."];
}
```

Unfortunately, the result is the same, the text is displayed on only one line.

Do you have any idea why and how I can overcome this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure that your UILabel has enough space (height set accordingly ?)

Comment: set UILabel Text style to "Attributed Text" in storyboard and then run

Comment: @Zach: check the label frame.

Comment: @SumitGarg I changed in the storyboard the text from "Plain" to "Attributed" but the display is still the same.

Comment: @dehlen According to the constraints of the auto layout, the label should have enough space to add some lines. Otherwise since the label is created in the storyboard I don't know how to set its height.

Comment: @VineeshTP I am not sure how to do it. I displayed the height and width of the label (display.frame.size.height/width) and it seems that the height is 20 and the width is 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dehlen was right the label was not having enough space.

I did not now that I should/could expand the size of the label manually in the storyboard. I also had to add a "Vertical spacing" constraint so that the auto layout was happy.